# Adding a Drop-Down Menu to Icon/Image

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, icons

I would like to add an icon within my .NET app (not in the header area), that has a menu within it.  So you click on the icon and a drop-down menu appears...very similar to a multi-level website menu.  I just don't have room for text, so I have to stick with a 24x24 icon.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to simply wire up an event handler for a click event, and when fired just have a panel with the drop-down menu inside, appear.